# Grab contacts and display them into a list view

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to store the list of contacts that are already stored in the contacts list into a List View. So far when I click the button nothing actually happens. There are no runtime errors; simply nothing happens. This is being run on a Google Nexus 7.

Here is the code.

```
 contactsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactsList);
        btnContacts = (Button) findViewById((R.id.btnContacts));
        StoreContacts = new ArrayList<String>();

        // toasts the user that their contacts are now being accessed
//        EnableRuntimePermission();

        btnContacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                GetContactsIntoArrayList();

                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        DisplayInformation.this,
                        R.layout.activity_display_information, // possibly change if it doesn't work
                        R.id.contactsList, StoreContacts
                );

                contactsList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                contactsList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}

    });


  public void GetContactsIntoArrayList() {

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use an ArrayAdapter. Use the CursorAdapter with databases

Comment: Also, `StoreContacts` is never changed and `GetContactsIntoArrayList` is never getting anything...

Comment: This might help, the question uses a CursorAdapter, the answer uses an ArrayAdapter in order to additionally show the phone number: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636406/displaying-the-phone-number-of-a-contact-in-android-contact-content-provider

Answer (score 0):

```
public void GetContactsIntoArrayList() {

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
StoreConacts.add(name);

    }
}
```